# git: replay commits on a different path

Tags: git

I've done a couple commits in "somedir" and have been continuously rebasing while I worked---my history is linear.  Now I wish I hadn't done my work in "somedir", but in a separate copy.  Can I replay my commits on "anotherdir", which is an identical copy of "somedir"?
(My commits are on a local topic branch, but that's not essential to the question.)

Comment: Why do you have two copies of the same directory in the repository? That's probably a bad idea. Maybe you could use a submodule instead?

Comment: If they're two directories in the same repository, why don't you just swap their names? `git mv somedir tmp && git mv anotherdir somedir && git mv tmp anotherdir`

Comment: @svick They represent two variants of the same game, which will diverge in the future and will have different features.

Comment: @Andrew That's a smart idea!  Unfortunately there are some commits there already (not interfering with my commits).  Also, I wouldn't want to pollute history with a swap.

Comment: @ngn, then I think they shouldn't be in the same repository. They should either be in each in its own repo, or on different branches in the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `anotherdir` as a remote of `somedir`, and push your changes.

In `somedir`, assuming the branch with your changes is called `current`:

```
git remote add anotherdir /path/to/anotherdir
git push anotherdir current
```

Then in `anotherdir` you can checkout the branch `current`.

Comment: That would work if `somedir` and `anotherdir` were repositories. My assumption was that they are part of the same repo. But it's not clear from the question, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I might have misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same repo.  Thanks anyway.